# Turning array with objects into array with specific key from that objects?

Tags: javascript

What I have is this:

```
const objArr = [
    {name: "John", id: 1}, 
    {name: "Marry", id: 2}, 
    {name: "Jack", id: 3}
  ]
```

And I want this:

```
const names = [
    "John",
    "Marry",
    "Jack"
  ]
```

How? Thanks!

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all yourself yet?

Comment: Clearly he asked question without even trying himself

Comment: There's no need for that, I am fetching some objects from server, doing this for hours and lost my self... Actually the first answer is correct and I already tried that but did not realize that it work... No need for minuses, I am just tired... Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return only the *name* property.

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
const objArr = [
    {name: "John", id: 1}, 
    {name: "Marry", id: 2}, 
    {name: "Jack", id: 3}
  ] 

const names = objArr.map(p => p.name);

console.log(names);
```

Comment: You should really have voted to close as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

here you go ;)

```
const names = objArr.map(person => person.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `map` method in combination with *destructuring* by passing a *callback* provided function as argument.

```js
const objArr = [{name: "John", id: 1}, {name: "Marry", id: 2}, {name: "Jack", id: 3}] 
console.log(objArr.map(({name}) => name));
```

Comment: You should really have voted to close as duplicate